# php PDO just INSERT one of several querys

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I have php PDO query and I want to insert several  `service_id` 's with just one `user_id` whith  this code :

```
   $user_id = 1 ;
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servername.'; dbname='.$db_name.';charset=utf8' , $db_username, $db_password);
        for($r=1;$r <= 10 ;$r++ )
        {
            $extra_services_item = 'extra_services_item'.$r ;
            if(isset($_POST[$extra_services_item]))
            {
                $service_id =   test_input( $_POST[$extra_services_item] ) ;    
                $ins_new_pro_q= "insert into `user_services` (user_id,service_id) values ('$user_id','$service_id') "; 
                $ins_new_pro = $db -> prepare($ins_new_pro_q);
                $ins_new_pro -> execute() ;
            }
        }
```

But it just inserts the first `service_id` how can I do this ? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you might want to move your PDO object creation outside of the loop since you can use the same object and it would be less connection requests to the MySQL server.

Secondly, are any of your fields in the table a primary key? If so, which one?

Comment: for this part :  you might want to move your PDO object creation outside of  .... | in my main code its out but here I wrote it inside by mistake , this is my dataa base :http://upload7.ir/uploads//2174efb26ad6b102d64696c5275c05a5f7f187df.jpg

Comment: If you do a `print "Check: $user_id, $service_id<br />";` inside the loop right before the SQL stuff, do you get 10 of them?

Comment: Oh also, unless I'm reading it incorrectly, if seems like you have the "user_id" field set as "Distinct values". I haven't used phpmyadmin for more than 5 years, so I might be reading it wrong. That **is** phpmyadmin, right?

Comment: yes ; I deleted user_id and service_id from db and created theme again , it works now !